# convert to asc order of array data using MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

how to make this data to asc order by user's first name and user's last name.

I got the response, want to sort the records by user's first name but it is taking from creation date I guess when using sort how can I make it base on user's first name and user's last name please guide

```
{
        "response": {
            "items": [
                {
                    "_id": "5e71f86bd300b313df52fb2f",
                    "last_message": {
                        "text": "Alex",
                        "users": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                                "first_name": "zack",
                                "last_name": "Write"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "texter": [
                        "alex",
                        "$0ctg"
                    ],
                    "title": "New group1",
                    "group": true,
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5e4a8afc3952132a08ae575e",
                            "first_name": "test3",
                            "last_name": "test4"
                        }
                    ],
                    "managers": [
                        "5e4a8afc3952132a08ae575e"
                    ],
                    "member": {
                        "_id": "5e4a8afc3952132a08ae575e",
                        "first_name": "test3",
                        "last_name": "test4"
                    }
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5e4e740f380054797d9db621",
                    "last_message": {
                        "text": "",
                        "users": [
                            {
                                "_id": "5e4a8d2d3952132a08ae5764",
                                "first_name": "yuhan",
                                "last_name": "jacob"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    "texter": [
                        "",
                        "",
                        "",
                        "",
                        "",
                        "new iphone x\n brand new iphone wv wwvqzwzvq had sqswgscq wow you wholeheartedly q \n $600.00",
                        "helo",
                        "hello",
                        "hi"
                    ],
                    "members": [
                        {
                            "_id": "5e4d0973babf2b74ca868f4d",
                            "first_name": "alex",
                            "last_name": "hales"
                        }
                    ],
                    "managers": [],
                    "member": {
                        "_id": "5e4d0973babf2b74ca868f4d",
                        "first_name": "alex",
                        "last_name": "hales"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

Tried 
 {
        $sort: {
          users: 1,
        }
      },
doesn't help much

Also if I would like to add two field asc desc order what would be the process in MongoDB

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this will help you !

```
{
    $sort: { "users.first_name": 1 }
},
```